# LED blinking pattern in C

Tags: c, embedded, led

I need to produce LED blinking pattern shown in the third axis (Resulting_pattern) in attached figure

[image: LED blinking pattern]

I have decided to implement this with two software oscillators. 
The first oscillator produces pulse signal with period 500 ms. The second one 
produces pulse signal with period 5000 ms. The outputs of both oscillators are 
processed by logic AND for resulting signal.

The software oscillator is implemented in following manner. There is one function
called OSC in my source code and the individual instances are modeled by C struct.

```
    typedef struct{
    float period;         // period of the oscillations (ms)
    BOOL start;           // oscillator start signal (start==TRUE, stop==FALSE)
    BOOL init;            // init==TRUE, initialize timer
    float delta;          // timeout for negation the output
    uint16_t start_time;  // captured state of the appropriate system timer
    uint16_t cycle_cnt;   // current cycle count
    TIMER tmr;                // used system timer
}Osc_t;


    void OSC(uint32_t output, Osc_t *p){

    uint16_t act_time;
    uint16_t elap_time;

    // oscillator start required?
    if(p->start){

        // reading value of system timer
        taskENTER_CRITICAL();
            switch(p->tmr){

                case T1MS:
                    act_time = Tmr_1ms;
                break;

                case T10MS:
                    act_time = Tmr_10ms;
                break;

                case T100MS:
                    act_time = Tmr_100ms;
                break;

            }
        taskEXIT_CRITICAL();

        // capture current state of appropriate system timer
        if(p->init){

            p->start_time = act_time;
            p->init  = FALSE;

        }

        // half period based on desired period and system timer used
        switch(p->tmr){

            case T1MS:
                p->delta = ((p->period)/2);
            break;

            case T10MS:
                p->delta = ((p->period)/(2*10));
            break;

            case T100MS:
                p->delta = ((p->period)/(2*100));
            break;

        }

        // current elapsed time
        elap_time = (act_time - (p->start_time));

        // half period elapsed?
        if(elap_time >= (p->delta)){

            // one cycle
            if(TestIfLogicSignalSet(output)){
                p->cycle_cnt++;
            }

            NegLogicSignal(output);
            p->start_time = act_time;

        }

    }else{

        ClearLogicSignal(output);
        p->cycle_cnt = 0;
        p->init = TRUE;

    }

}
```

I have defined several global variables ("software timers") called Tmr_1ms, 
Tmr_10ms and Tmr_100ms for timing purposes. These variables are incremented in 
an ISR which is invoked every 1 ms

```
    // 1 ms counter
Tmr_1ms++;      // 0 ms - 65535 ms

// 10 ms counter
if(++cnt_01 == 10){
    Tmr_10ms++;     // 0 ms - 655350 ms
    cnt_01 = 0;
}

// 100 ms counter
if(++cnt_02 == 100){
    Tmr_100ms++;    // 0 ms - 6553500 ms
    cnt_02 = 0;
}
```

The software timer used by oscillator instance is determined by TIMER tmr item 
in Osc_t struct.

```
 // system timers
typedef enum{
    T100MS,
    T10MS,
    T1MS
}TIMER;
```

The complete implementation is following

```
    // main oscillator init
Main_Oscillator_state.period = 500;   // 500 ms
Main_Oscillator_state.tmr = T1MS;
Main_Oscillator_state.init = TRUE;

// mask oscillator init
Mask_Oscillator_state.period = 5000;    // 5000 ms
Mask_Oscillator_state.tmr = T1MS;
Mask_Oscillator_state.init = TRUE;

Main_Oscillator_state.start = TRUE;
Mask_Oscillator_state.start = TRUE;

// main oscillator
OSC(LMainOsc, &Main_Oscillator_state);
// mask oscillator
OSC(LMaskOsc, &Mask_Oscillator_state);
// resulting alarm blinking pattern
AND_02(LBlinkPat, LMainOsc,DIR, LMaskOsc,DIR);
```

The problem is that this implementation is functional only in case I place
the OSC and AND_02 functions into ISR which is invoked every 1 ms. If I place
these functions into ISR which is invoked every 20 ms there are errors in 
blinking pattern (the first and fifth pulse in the resulting pattern have 
sometimes shorter duration). Does anybody have any idea what could be the reason? I need to place the OSC and AND_02 functions call into 20 ms ISR.
My idea was that this inaccuracy is caused by reading the Tmr_1ms in 20 ms ISR 
and the fact that the half periods of the oscillations are 250 ms (= 12.5*20 ms i.e. not integer multiple of 20 ms) and 2500 ms (= 125*20 ms).

Comment: You are overcomplicating the simple things. Later I will show you another way

Comment: Thank you for your reaction PeterJ_01.

Comment: What is the question exactly ? For the only question mark I see you answered yourself : half period is not a multiple of 20ms. Anyway if there is any delay during init OR if timers are not on same clock (they will drift differently) you accept to have an error up to 20ms in worst case.

Comment: Thank you for your reaction Julien. I wasn't sure whether my hypothesis is correct. What about to take T10MS in 20 ms ISR. It should be OK. Isn't it?

Comment: @Steve you can see any blinking patterns for as  many leds you want using only one timer https://github.com/diymat/ARM-blog-libraries-and-examples. For your example you need to use a bit more complicated version (you need to change #define `GLOBALONOFFSUPPORT 0` to `#define GLOBALONOFFSUPPORT 1`

Comment: @PeterJ_01 Thank you for your answer. Your solution is unfortunately very different from the rest of my code. I have implemented the whole application logic with similar blocks like the above given oscillators. I have defined some timers, counters and so on. I need to preserve the implementation style for readability and maintainability resasons. I have been struggling with finding the reasons why my implementation is fully functional only in ISR which is invoked every 1 ms.